# undefined parse transformation "lager_transformation" ejabberd 17.01

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

i am trying to configure ejabberd module using in windows 8.1 following link 
https://github.com/Mingism/ejabberd-stanza-ack 
ejabberd version 17.01
erlang version 8.3
 this is the command i am using

erlc -I ${C:\Program%Files\ejabberd-17.01\lib\ejabberd-17.01\include} mod_stanza_ack.erl

i put mod_stanza_ack.erl also inside include folder but it gives lagger_transformation error. Is it a different version issue? this link also says that it is for ejabberd version 13.x. I think it can also work in latest version. What i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to move the file `mod_stanza_ack.erl` into an include directory, but put it in a working directory. Then start a command window in that directory and execute:

```
erlc -I "C:/Program Files/ejabberd-17.01/lib/ejabberd-17.01/src" mod_stanza_ack.erl
```

**Note** you have to put the source path into "double quotes", and use "/" and not "\" for the path, even in window (at least it works like this, and i did not try to use double back slash "\", a single back slash escapes the next character!)

**Note 2** the tested version 13 of ejabberd is 4 years old, You should be prepared to face some compatibility issues using an earlier one.

**Edit**

You need at least these 3 source files: `logger.hrl, ejabberd.hrl, jlib.hrl` they are included in `ejabberd-stanza-ack.erl`.  In the current ejabberd version (master branch), the header files (*.hrl) are in the include directory, as usual, but they doesn't content the definition of `xmlel` record which is used by `ejabberd-stanza-ack.erl` so you cannot use this version.

In the ejabberd 13, the header files are in the src directory - weird ! - , they include the necessary record definitions (at least at first glance...). So you should use this version. If you try to use a more recent one, you must verify that it is still using the `xmlel` record definition, and adapt the command line with the real location of the header files.

Comment: still that error. i tried with double quote. also there is no src directry in ejabberd folder. i installed it through windows installer